# Proving that a polynomial over $K[t]$ is congruent modulo $m$ to a unique polynomial in $K[t]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, congruences

$K$ is a field, and $K[t]$ is the set of polynomials over $K$. If we pick a polynomial $m$ in $K[t]$ we could perform arithmetic modulo $m$, in the sense that a polynomial $a$ is congruent to another polynomial $b$ if $a-b$ is divisible by $m$ in $K[t]$.

The author then claims that a polynomial $a$ is congruent modulo $m$ to a unique polynomial in $K[t]$. He gives a proof by contradiction, assuming that $a=r$(mod $m$) and $a=s$(mod  $m$), but he then assumes that the degree of $s$ is smaller than the degree of $m$, but gives no explanation of such assumption.

How could one prove that the latter statement that the degree of $s$ is smaller than the degree of $m$?

Alternitavely, if its easier to the repliers, how could one complete the proof in another way?

---

Besides, wouldn't it be possible to say that

$$a=m+g_1$$
$$a=2m+g_2$$

(...)

$$a=nm+g_n$$

So that $a$ would be congruent to all the (different) $g_i$, contradicting the author's statement?

Where is my mistake, then?

---

I would really appreciate any help/thoughts.

Comment: "A polynomial in $K[t]$ is congruent, modulo $m$, to a unique polynomial _of degree smaller than $\deg(m)$_." That's the actual statement and the reason for assuming that the degree of $s$ is smaller than $\deg(m)$.

Comment: Yeah...that was it